# Restore the original order based on many incomplete ordered sets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set

Let's say my original data is

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

It got corrupted and all I have is a few **incomplete sets** where the order is valid but not all elements are present.

```
1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12
1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12
2, 4, 7, 9, 10, 11
4, 7, 9, 12
```

etc.

I also have the list of all original elements without any order.

I need to restore as much original data as possible. I have no guarantee that I have enough information to restore everything. I need to make the most sense of what I have and figure out which parts are reliable.

There may be complications (but I'd solve the problem without them first):

Order of the incomplete sets is mostly valid but may have a few mistakes here and there, it's written by humans.

I may have additional information for every pair of elements in the incomplete sets like

- "*there is certainly nothing between    5 and 6*",
- "*there is certainly something else between 7 and 12 but I'm not sure how many and what exactly*",
- "*there may be or may not be anything between 3 and 4*",
- "*there is exactly one unknown item between 7 and 9*"

I'd like to incorporate that information into the algorithm to restore more data.

**My best idea so far:**

Use the incomplete arrays in the sorting function like this: conclude that A > B if there exists an incomplete set in which B precedes A. If there is no set in which both A and B are present return that A == B.

What I don't like about it is that I have no idea which parts are completely restored and which are random. To kind of help that I'm going to shuffle the original list of elements, sort again and see which elements change place and which don't. And do that a few thousand times (The number of elements in the list is < 50 so I can use the most bulldozerish methods on this problem)

Any better suggestions?

Comment: You may also want to consider the transitive property with your initial idea. e.g. if A > B and B > C then A > C, even if there is no incomplete set where C precedes A. I don't think this will improve the ordering of the sort, but I believe it can be used to make the sort more efficient with the right data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build directed graph from your incomplete sets and make  [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Some errors might be found as cycles (there are no cycles in directed acyclic graph)

Comment: This will indeed find *some* order consistent with the given orders, if it exists (i.e. if the inputs do not describe a graph with a directed cycle).  But you would also want to detect whether this ordering is unique; to do that, find the **critical path** instead of topologically sorting.  If there is some vertex not on the critical path then its exact position in the order is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

Build a directed graph as MBo suggests. If the resulting graph is a directed acyclic graph (DAG), that counts as validation of the original data, and it's possible to perform a topological sort to recover information about the original order.

Some of the additional information can be incorporated into the graph, if you think all your information is reliable. For example, "there is certainly nothing between 5 and 6" means (if it is understood that 5 -> 6) that every edge of the graph from v to 6 (v not equal to 5) can be replaced by an edge from v to 5. "There may or may not be anything between 3 and 4": all this tells us is 3 -> 4, if it even says that much.

The other information is harder to use. "Something between 7 and 12" can be incorporated into the digraph as 7 -> 12, but the "something" part can't, as far as I can see. There might be a way to use it by enlarging the graph to include "something" vertices, but I can't get it to work. Instead, I recommend getting your topsort algorithm to spit out every topsort (provided there aren't too many) and evaluating them by how many additional constraints they are consistent with. As a bonus you'll find out how many different answers are possible. You can also use it while you are topsorting, e.g., if you're looking for an item to come immediately after 7, don't pick 12, but that feels messy to me, and you won't get any outcome at all if the information is contradictory.

If the resulting graph is not a DAG, you can still separate it into strongly connected components (e.g., Tarjan's algorithm). The strongly connected components are the parts that are not reliable. The strongly connected components will themselves form a DAG which can be topsorted, but each component of size bigger than 1 vertex will need some further special treatment. One way to handle this is to try to find a **minimum feedback arc set**, i.e., the minimum number of edges to eliminate in a strongly connected component to turn it into a DAG. The minimum feedback arc set problem is NP-hard, but the problem is "fixed-parameter tractable": http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1411509.1411511. Less reasoned approaches will probably work, too, like identifying a cycle and removing a random edge in the cycle until there are no more cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a some algorithm can be if you take a longest string and try to compare this string to all others by two neithebor symbols( begin and end included too): if there is something between it in other strings add this to the longest string, and start again. If nothing to add check next pair.